# how to convert var data to int type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**I have "Products table" with following fields**
PID int,
product_name varchar(),
product_price int

**"Cart table" with following fields**
cart_ID
user_id
PID

**So I want to display cart items of logged in user**
For example if user_ID=100 is logged in , then only his cart items should be displayed to him, with all the product details.
**Am using asp.net with entity framework**

```
 public ActionResult Cart()
    {
        Products pro = new Products();
        Cart cart =new Cart();

        var productID=db.cartDetails.Where(pid=>pid.productId==cart.productId && cart.user_id==session["user_ID"]);
        return View(db.productsDetails.Where(pid => pid.productId == productID));
    }
```

Now problem arise, "ProductID" being var type i cannot compare it with "pid=>pid.productid".
**How to store productid in int List, so that i can compare it with individual productid from product table to show product details?**

Answer (score 0):

<del>try to convert it before check</del>

<del>var productID=int.Parse(db.cartDetails.Where(pid=>pid.productId==cart.productId).ProductId);
    return View(db.productsDetails.Where(pid => pid.productId == productID));</del>

**EDIT**
`db.cartDetails.Where(pid=>pid.productId==cart.productId`

this will return object of product or something so need to change your code in to

```
 var product = db.cartDetails.Where(pid=>pid.productId==cart.productId).FirstOrDefault();
if(product!= null){
  return View(db.productsDetails.Where(pid => pid.productId == product.productID));
}
```

Comment: can `db.cartDetails.Where(pid=>pid.productId==cart.productId)` return a int?

Comment: no `db.cartDetails.Where(pid=>pid.productId==cart.productId).ProductId` will return

Comment: In that case why do you think the cast is needed?

Comment: no it's not working, shows nothing on the cart page,
One more thing , i need to && compare each product in cart with the user_ID , so that only logged in users products get listed.
But after doing so , i got null reference exception.
{var productID=db.cartDetails.Where(pid=>pid.productId==cart.productId && cart.user_id==session["user_ID"]);
}

Answer (score 0):

```
db.cartDetails.Where(pid=>pid.productId==cart.productId) returns a `WhereListIterator<CartDetail>` object.
```

So you'll need to to do something like -

```
var productID=db.cartDetails.Where(pid=>pid.productId==cart.productId).FirstOrDefault();
return View(db.productsDetails.Where(pid => pid.productId == productID.productID));
```

Comment: var productID=db.cartDetails.Where(pid=>pid.productId==cart.productId) will not return you CartDetails object. it will return a collection of CartDatail object.

Comment: I was just showing an example.Anyways updated. Thanks.

Comment: no it's not working, shows nothing on the cart page,
One more thing , i need to && compare each product in cart with the user_ID , so that only logged in users products get listed.
But after doing so , i got null reference exception.
{var productID=db.cartDetails.Where(pid=>pid.productId==cart.productId && cart.user_id==session["user_ID"]);
}

Comment: what do you get after the `FirstOrDefault`? It might be null ?

Comment: That means there no `cartDetail` matching the `cart.productId`. Or `cart.user_id==session["user_ID"]` isn't true. Check if `session["user_ID"]` has any data in it.

Comment: What i want to do is first get all the product_id's of user from "cart table" by comparing uid_id(Logged in user) with user_id in cart table.
, then displaying product details of those product_id's from "product Table ".
So obviously i need to store multiple product_id's ,so that i can populate their data on the cart page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

**Edit :**

First thing you can not compare directly session["user_ID"] with int datatype field as you are doing in you comment `cart.user_id==session["user_ID"]` follow updated code.

```
var userID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["user_ID"]); //And please check first session is null or not than go ahead.
//Here as you said now you can compare productID and userId as follow.
//And if these both conditions will be satisfied than you will get cartDetails table first record otherwise it will return null value
var cartDetail = db.cartDetails.Where(pid => pid.productId == cart.productId && pid.user_id == userID).FirstOrDefault();
if(cartDetail != Null)
{
    return View(db.productsDetails.Where(pid => pid.productId == cartDetail.productID));
}
```

[FirstOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx) Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements.

My First line code return you `int` productID if it is not null.

Comment: no it's not working, shows nothing on the cart page,
One more thing , i need to && compare each product in cart with the user_ID , so that only logged in users products get listed.
But after doing so , i got null reference exception.
{var productID=db.cartDetails.Where(pid=>pid.productId==cart.productId && cart.user_id==session["user_ID"]);
}

Comment: inspect the `cart` obect.

Comment: will cartDetail store collection of product_id's ,as one user will have more than one product in his cart?

Comment: What i want to do is first get all the product_id's of user from "cart table" by comparing uid_id(Logged in user) with user_id in cart table.
, then displaying product details of those product_id's from "product Table ".
So obviously i need to store multiple product_id's ,so that i can populate their data on the cart page.